# Traveling to the US on a visa that is soon to expire

Tags: visas, usa

I am traveling to the US with my daughter in May 2018. Her US visa expires in October 2018. We are back in our home country in a month. Does she have to have at least 6 months left on her visa at the time of entry in the USA.

Comment: you can enter a country as long as the visa is valid and you will exit before the expiry

Comment: You can travel to the US even on the last date of your visa validity. SO has plenty of questions about that already

Comment: @Newton for some countries, including the US, it's not even necessary to leave before the visa expires.  In the US, the duration of stay is specified by the immigration officer at the port of entry, and it has nothing to do with the visa's expiration date.